# Metricbeat + SQL module

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I have the SQL queries which use regexp_replace function with special character  '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)', '\1\3' This was not working when I start the metricbeat. I used double " for entire query still its not working.. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer your question without seeing full statement, but I suspect the issue is in not escaping escape character. Metricbeat is using yaml syntax that treats `\` as an escape character in strings. So, try adding an extra `\` before each `\`. If that doesn't work, please post the whole configuration snippet not just the regex and the error message that you are getting.

Comment: is there any way to escape the # charchter in oracle password in sql.yml file.

Comment: Just put it in quotes.